# Parameter group changes not reflecting on Aurora Serverless DB cluster

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to update the **binlog_format** parameter in my Aurora mysql 5.6.10 (Data API enabled) instance to **ROW** but I'm not able to change it.

I've updated my custom parameter group accordingly but those changes do not reflect on the cluster when I run `show variables like 'binlog_format'`.

- Right after changing the parameter group, the cluster goes into `Modifying` state but after that finishes the parameter hasn't been updated.
- I can't seem to find an option to reboot or stop the cluster on the AWS UI.
- Using the CLI, I get this error trying to stop the cluster: `An error occurred (InvalidDBClusterStateFault) when calling the StopDBCluster operation: Stop-db-cluster is not supported for these configurations`.
- Tried changing the capacity settings but that didn't do anything.

Is there any other way I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Luis, was there anything else that you'd like answered in this question?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to check if the specific property modification is supported by serverless engine or not by running this command:

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-parameters --db-cluster-parameter-group-name <param-group-name>
```

If you read the output from above statement, it says 'provisioned' for SupportedEngineModes:

```
       {
            "ParameterName": "binlog_format",
            "ParameterValue": "OFF",
            "Description": "Binary logging format for replication",
            "Source": "system",
            "ApplyType": "static",
            "DataType": "string",
            "AllowedValues": "ROW,STATEMENT,MIXED,OFF",
            "IsModifiable": true,
            "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot",
            "SupportedEngineModes": [
                "provisioned"
            ]
        }
```

Ideal state is something like this for a modifiable parameter:

```
       {
            "ParameterName": "character_set_server",
            "Description": "The server's default character set.",
            "Source": "engine-default",
            "ApplyType": "dynamic",
            "DataType": "string",
            "AllowedValues": "big5,dec8,cp850,hp8,koi8r,latin1,latin2,swe7,ascii,ujis,sjis,hebrew,tis620,euckr,koi8u,gb2312,greek,cp1250,gbk,latin5,armscii8,utf8,ucs2,cp866,keybcs2,macce,macroman,cp852,latin7,utf8mb4,cp1251,utf16,cp1256,cp1257,utf32,binary,geostd8,cp932,eucjpms",
            "IsModifiable": true,
            "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot",
            "SupportedEngineModes": [
                "provisioned",
                "serverless"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Aurora does support Start and Stop APIs now, so I'm surprised that you were not able to use it.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-aurora-stop-and-start/

Can you try using them through CLI?

On a separate note, if you just want to reboot the engine for the param change to flow in, you just need to use the `reboot-db-instance` API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/reboot-db-instance.html

Comment: `reboot-db-instance` is for db cluster right? What we are looking is to restart/reboot serverless db so that parameter change can flow.
DB cluster you can easily restart