# How does `pending-reboot` apply method works for AWS Aurora Serverless database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an AWS Aurora serverless v1 database, it's managed by Terraform, and I specified a static parameter `tls_version`and used `pending_reboot` as the `apply_method`, then I applied the changes in terraform.

From [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_RebootCluster.html#aurora-mysql-survivable-replicas), it says: "*For example, suppose that you modify the parameters within a parameter group or associate a different parameter group with your cluster. In these cases, **you must reboot the cluster for the changes to take effect**.* "

My question is: after I applied Terraform, when I checked the parameter group, I didn't see anywhere showing me `pending`, **do I have to reboot the cluster**? And if so, **how can I reboot the Aurora serverless cluster**, because I checked AWS console, couldn't find a reboot button:

[image]

But when I check a non-serverless cluster, I can see there is a 'reboot' button for its instance,I'm so confused, what should I do to make the parameter groups to take effect and how can I verify it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manually reboot an Aurora Serverless cluster. When [modifying](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Modifying.html) the parameter group, the changes are applied immediately:

> For Aurora, when you modify a DB cluster, only changes to the DB cluster identifier, IAM DB authentication, and New master password settings are affected by the Apply immediately setting. All other modifications are applied immediately, regardless of the value of the Apply immediately setting.

Not only that, but `tls_version` is for provisioned clusters only. Run

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-parameters \
--db-cluster-parameter-group-name default.aurora-mysql5.7 | 
jq '.Parameters[] | select (.ParameterName=="tls_version")'

{
            "ParameterName": "tls_version",
            "Description": "The protocols permitted by the server for encrypted connections.",
            "Source": "engine-default",
            "ApplyType": "static",
            "DataType": "list",
            "AllowedValues": "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2",
            "IsModifiable": true,
            "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot",
            "SupportedEngineModes": [
                "provisioned"
            ]
        }
```

and you can see that it is only applicable for the "provisioned" engine mode.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790826/parameter-group-changes-not-reflecting-on-aurora-serverless-db-cluster for a similar issue

Comment: 'tls_version is for provisioned clusters only'-do you have a link of where this is mentioned in AWS doc? From my reading and testing,  (I configured it from Terraform) and it looks like it's compatible with Serverless engine-mode and in the parameter group I can clearly see the Value has been set to the one I wanted.

Comment: @Cecilia it's implicit in the description: `"SupportedEngineModes":"provisioned"`. If it were for serverless as well, the result would say `"SupportedEngineModes":"provisioned", "serverless"` like it does for a parameter like `time_zone`: `aws rds describe-db-cluster-parameters --db-cluster-parameter-group-name default.aurora-mysql5.7 |  jq '.Parameters[] | select (.ParameterName=="time_zone")'`

Comment: AWS docs are not very easy to follow... maybe they just gave us an example, I've seen this situation before. Until I see they say it's only available for one particular type, I'll still think it works for Serverless engine as my testing result in Terraform didn't complain anything like 'this parameter isn't supported' or something else, and I can see the value has been set to the one I want in AWS console.